# How can I use CURLOPT_USERPWD in wp_remote_post?

Tags: headers, authentication, http, curl, wp-remote-post

I'm trying to setup a proper cURL call in WordPress so am using wp_remote_post(). However, I'm having trouble authenticating the user via wp_remote_post(). Any idea how to convert the following to be used in wp_remote_post?

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");`

Full example of proper cURL basic auth is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064360/1543310).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Authorization` header. Example:

```
$auth = base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password );

$args = [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Basic $auth"
    ],
    'body'    => $body,
];      

$response      = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Still not working for me, but this seems to be the right direction. I'm guessing it's something with my other header parameters.

Comment: @JeremiahPrummer Start with the most basic headers, then add more until it breaks or works. :) I had a similar issue recently where the `Content-Type` header lead to an authorization error … some APIs are not nice.

Comment: And yeah, I'm the first tester of this API so it needs some work... Either way, got it working thanks to you. This was extremely helpful